# Select from multiple tables using 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `user`, `data`.

In the `user` table I have the following columns:

```
id | username | name    | country | time
 1 | test     | Joseph  | US      | 2013
 2 | franc    | Kennedy | US      | 2014
 3 | trumo    | Dale    | UK      | 2013
```

In the `data` table I have the following columns:

```
id | username | best_time
 1 | franc    | 3455
 2 | trumo    | 4485
 3 | franc    | 1231
```

I actually want to select all the `Name`, `Country` from the `User` table and the `best_time` from the `Data` table, BASED on the `Data` `username` column.

Example:

`1 | franc | 3455 | Kennedy | US`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user.name, user.country, data.best_time from user, data where user.user_name = data.user_name;
```